# Reply to the one sending the form

Tags: php, forms, contacts, contact-form

I have read many questions like this in Stackoverflow during the last hour but I keep trying things and my script keeps crashing and I cannot solve my issue. I have this php script for my contact form. It works perfectly but the only problem is that when I receive the email it comes from CGI-Mailer cgi-mailer@kundenserver.de

I want it to be from the person sending the form so you can directly reply to them from your email. I would appreciate some help, my php knowledge is really low and that is probably why I am implementing every one of your tips wrong. I just want to know what part of my script should be changed and for what. Thanks!

```
<?php
// check if fields passed are empty
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "Arguments missing!";
    return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// create email body and send it    
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; // put your email
$email_subject = "Web Form";
$email_body =  "New message. \n\n".
               "Details:\n\n".
               "Name: $name \n\n".
               "Email: $email_address\n\n".
               "Messaje: $message";    
$headers = 'From: Web-Form@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $email_address . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Using this code I found in a different post in stackoverflow I solved one part of the problem. Now the message shows Web-Form@mydomain.com as the name of the sender which is ok. At least is something I put. The problem is that when I click on reply in gmail it replies to my own email, to the one receiving the form instead of the one sending it.

Comment: Your first code has `Reply to:`, the second has `Reply-to:`. Which is in your actual code? It should be `Reply-to:`.

Comment: @Hector de Prada you have put `Reply-To: your-own-mail-id`, try this `'Reply-To: Web-Form@mydomain.com' . "\r\n"` .

Comment: @Barmar My code is the second one. I change the headers of the first one for the ones in the second one.

Comment: The second code should work. If you look at the headers in gmail, do you see the `Reply-to` header?

Comment: Yes @Barmar but if i type a reply in gmail the email address in the address box is my own, not the sender.

Comment: @keviveks But the problem now is that I reply to Web-Form@mydomain.com but I want to reply to the one using the form. For example: michael12@gmail.com

Comment: Sounds like gmail is ignoring the Reply-to header, but I find that difficult to believe.

Comment: @Barmar with that code (the second one) it looks like it works but when I reply (I have actually reply last time), I am the one receiving the email. Definitely not the person I wanted to that filled the form.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why that's happening. If there's a `Reply-to` header, replies should always be sent there. Can you try putting my address barmar@alum.mit.edu into the form, I'll look at the email I get.

Comment: Solve it @Barmar Let´s see what you think about this. I changed the code in the headers to: $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
   'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); I think that the first header was interfiering with the second one.

Comment: Sorry @Barmar where I forgot to say that I change all the email_address for email_from. I saw it in another php script

Comment: You don't need `Reply-to` if it's the same as `From`, since the only purpose of `Reply-to` is to override the `From` address.

Comment: The name of the variable shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: You were right @Barmar I actually was able to make it work with only: 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

Answer (score 0):

I changed my header to:

```
   $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

The entire script is like this now:

```
        <?php
    // check if fields passed are empty
    if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
       empty($_POST['email'])       ||
       empty($_POST['message']) ||
       !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
       {
        echo "Arguments missing!";
        return false;
       }

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email_from = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    // create email body and send it    
    $to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; // put your email
    $email_subject = "Web Form";
    $email_body =  "New message. \n\n".
                   "Details:\n\n".
                   "Name: $name \n\n".
                   "Email: $email_from\n\n".
                   "Messaje: $message";    
   $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    return true;            
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change $email-address to $email
Add

```
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n"
```

Comment: Why does the variable name matter?